# Estoy haciendo un ranking en un proyecto de android y no se como enviar y obtener los datos "nombre" y "score"

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, firestore

Regreso a esta tierra de sabiduría con otra duda existencial, estuve indagando en foros y tutoriales sobre como hacer un ranking para mi app pero no encuentro nada relacionado (al menos no con las tecnologías que utilizo).

Tengo una app que es un quiz con pantalla principal y botones que envían al jugador a las distintas modalidades del juego, cuando el jugador acaba alguna de las partidas, se trae un score obtenido de la cantidad de preguntas respondidas consigo al menú principal donde puede verlo.

Todo bien hasta ese punto, el asunto es que en el menú principal quiero mostrar con un RecyclerView o algún widget un Ranking donde aparezcan los 20 jugadores con los puntajes mas altos de todos y no se como realizarlo.

Estoy utilizando Firebase para esto ya que la Autentificación la tengo incorporada con la misma y se me había ocurrido obtener uno de esos datos que quiero que muestre (El nombre, en este caso obtenido del Gmail como en la autentificación) y el score subiéndolo a la Base de datos a medida que vaya subiendo el puntaje, requiero de su ayuda ya que no se como continuar.

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

**EDIT**
Para mas claridad, quiero que se pueda obtener de la app cliente esos datos, guardarlos en la DB en firebase o otra tecnologia que se recomiende y mostrarla en la app cliente en el Reciclerview o widget que sea conveniente.

**Adjunto el main activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.Objects;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView profileImage;
    TextView user_id, scored;
    Button bntfacil, bntnormal, bntdificil, bnttimetrial, bntajustes;

    int sscore = 0;


    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        user_id = findViewById(R.id.name);
        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        scored = findViewById(R.id.scoreee);



        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(Objects.requireNonNull(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).toString())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_profile_icon_free_vector)
                    .into(profileImage);
        }


        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            user_id.setText(user.getDisplayName());
        } else {
            finish();
        }



        bntfacil = findViewById(R.id.facil);
        bntfacil.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent facil = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzEasyActivity.class); //llama a la activity en modo facil
            startActivity(facil);
        });
        bntnormal = findViewById(R.id.Intermedio);
        bntnormal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent normal = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzNormalActivity.class);
            startActivity(normal);
        });
        bntdificil = findViewById(R.id.dificil);
        bntdificil.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent dificil = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzHardActivity.class);
            startActivity(dificil);
        });
        bnttimetrial = findViewById(R.id.contrarrelog);
        bnttimetrial.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent contrarreloj = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzTimeTrialActivity.class);
            startActivity(contrarreloj);
        });
        bntajustes = findViewById(R.id.ajustes);
        bntajustes.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent ajustes = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
            startActivity(ajustes);
        });
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences datos = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sscore=datos.getInt("puntos", 0);
        scored.setText("Score: "+sscore);

    }
}
```

**Adjunto el layuot del main activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    tools:context=".QuizzEasyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/titulo_juego"
        android:text="@string/quizz"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/titulo_juego"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/user_id"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreee"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="scoress"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ajustes"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ajustes" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/facil"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/easy"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/Intermedio"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/normal"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dificil"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/very_hard_boy"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contrarrelog"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Intermedio"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/time_trial" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="660dp"
        android:layout_height="365dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/scoreee"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**
El RcyclerView ya esta incorporado en el layout y la app ya esta conectada a Firebase, el asunto es que no se como enviar el nombre de usuario y el score a Firebase y obtenerlo luego en el recyclerView

Comment: Recuerda que es recomendable mostrar lo que has tratado, revisar [ask] modifica tu pregunta y obtendrás la ayuda requerida, saludos.

Comment: La lógica de lo que quieres hacer tiene bastante sentido y usar un RecyclerView también es una decisión acertada. No has indicado cuál es el problema.

Comment: El problema es, que no se como hacerlo, no existe info (al menos de lo que encontre) que me resuelva esta duda

Comment: *El problema es, que no se como hacerlo, no existe info (al menos de lo que encontre) que me resuelva esta duda*... Es que ni siquiera queda claro **cuál es tu duda** ¿? ¿Ya creaste tu RecyclerView? ¿Ya conectas a Firebase? ¿Ya obtienes sin problemas los datos que quieres de Firebase? Si todo eso funciona, ahora llena el RecyclerView con esos datos. Creo que lo primero es que tengas claro lo que necesitas hacer, luego, si algo no funciona, te ayudaremos a resolverlo.

Comment: El RcyclerView ya esta incorporado en el layout y la app ya esta conectada a Firebase, el asunto es que no se como enviar el nombre de usuario y el score a Firebase y obtenerlo luego en el recyclerView, lamento no haberlo especificado en la pregunta, ya lo acabo de hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una serie de pasos a seguir para lo que quieres hacer:

1. Create tu base de datos en Firebase, utiliza una buena lógica como podría ser:
   Tabla Score:
   -Usuario(PK)
   -Score
2. Crea tu modelo Score en Android con los mismos atributos que la tabla en Firebase.
3. Cada vez que se acabe una partida, añade un nuevo registro a Firebase (te recomiendo usar update para aquellos que hayan jugado antes e insert para aquellos que nunca jugaron, obviamente).
4. Cada vez que muestres ese RecyclerView haz una petición a Firebase y traete 20 registros ordenados por score ASC, utiliza ChatGPT para ver como sería la instrucción, almacénalos en un ArrayList (que será el que le pases al RecyclerView), haz todo esto en el metodo OnSucces del objeto FirebaseFirestore.

Te recomiendo que te mires tutoriales sino has utilizado nunca Firebase, te pueden servir aquellos como:
-Como implementar Firebase en Android.
-Insertar registros en Firebase desde Android.
-Etc...

También te aconsejo utilizar ChatGPT para que te ayude a ver las sentencias que se pueden realizar y no tener que calentarte tú la cabeza, como:

```
mibase.collection("productos")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Producto producto = documentSnapshot.toObject(Producto.class);
                        System.out.println(producto.getName());
                        productos.add(producto);
                    }
                    recAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productos);
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recAdapter);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    showToast("No se pudo conectar a la bdd");
                }
            });
```

En este código, accedo a mi Firestore Database, a la colección productos y me traigo todos sus registros, si no da ningún fallo, los introduzco en mi arrayList y posterior en el adapter.